# @Controller, @Service, @Repository beans fails on @EnableTransactionManagement in mode = AdviceMode.PROXY or default fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, proxy, aop

Why using **@EnableTransactionManagement** in default mode or PROXY mode attempts against beans creation like *@Controller*, *@Service*, and *@Repositories*. I don't discard another kind of beans targeting this bad behavior.

*I have a project with*:

- SpringBoot ***2.1.8.RELEASE*** + JPA + Rest Controller
- PostgreSQL 9.6
- ***@Transactional*** annotation on methods like *save*, *update* and *delete* (also, batch delete)

It creates proxy classes and nulls the remaining beans in the ApplicationContext.

[image: EnableTransactionManagement default/PROXY advice mode]

Comment: No it doesn't. The proxy doesn't contain anything. The proxy adds  behavior and wraps another instance of your service. That instance has the actual dependencies. Method calls go into the proxy, additional behavior is excuted (start/end transaction etc.) then the method is called on the wrapped instance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default mode is **PROXY**.  When **ASPECTJ** advice mode is set, all the beans are injected in the right place. [Check Spring current docs on the subject](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html).

> The `mode()` attribute controls how advice is applied: If the mode is `AdviceMode.PROXY` (the default), then the other attributes control the behavior of the proxying. Please note that proxy mode allows for interception of calls through the proxy only; local calls within the same class cannot get intercepted that way.
>
> Note that if the `mode()` is set to `AdviceMode.ASPECTJ`, then the value of the `proxyTargetClass()` attribute will be ignored. Note also that in this case the spring-aspects module JAR must be present on the classpath, with compile-time weaving or load-time weaving applying the aspect to the affected classes. There is no proxy involved in such a scenario; local calls will be intercepted as well.

*Like this:*

[image: EnableTransactionManagement ASPECTJ advice mode]

Still, @Transactional methods fail. Due to "**TransactionRequiredException**", so ASPECTJ does not solve the problem in persistence layer, only grants beans injection (maybe no platform transaction manager is created). What to do next?

*See the transaction exception:*

[image: Transaction Exception]

**!!! Solution:**

When working with transactions, the scope has to be shared in the beans chain: @Service(also, caller method)<-@Repository(also, transactional method), @Service context (class, method) shall be marked as @Transactional. Applies to annotated methods or classes in the call stack that ends in transactional operation (*bottom-up* approach).

*Annotation sequence:*

1. ***@EnableTransactionManagement*** (in @Configuration alike classes or @SpringBootApplication -autoconfiguration-)
2. ***@Transactional*** annotated method/classes in beans injection chain (*bottom-up*: persistent method/class, then @Service/@Component layers)
3. ***@Autowired*** annotation on beans candidates (*Service instance* in @Controller class, *Repository instance* in @Service class)

**Note:** Spring AOP does not create **proxy** properties from functional interfaces based features, only object instances so recommended is using methods encapsulating persistence logic.

*e.g*

```
Function<T, R> function 
BiFunction<T1,T2,R> function 
Supplier<T> supplier
...
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer in order to close the question. :-)

Comment: There is nothing broken and this just switches the way AOP is applied.

Comment: Still, it only works using a Unit Test. I have integration tests calling the Web API, then all the beans (with Spring AOP) are injected. But, when the application runs in production calling the endpoint ends in NullPointerException because of @Service<-@Repository are null. Then, I tested switching with ASPECTJ (with and without spring-boot-aop-starter) happens in reverse (beans chain is injected, no proxy classes but @Transactional methods give expected transaction exception on "update/delete" operation)